# I wanna take input from textfield and store that input in variables....any idea?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to retrieve data from textfield and store it inside a list directly or through variables....so how can I do that...any idea?
it's not the complete code ik but I think u get an idea...

```
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: const [
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Title',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Amount',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: Text("Add Transaction"),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Text editing controller

```
TextEditingController text1 = TextEditingController ();
```

Assign this controller to text field by using

```
controller: text1,
```

Now if you use

```
print(text1.text);
```

You should see the values of textfield

Answer (score 0):

You can add a text variable and TextEditingController and set as textfield controller property value.

`final textController = TextEditingController();`

When the button taps, you will get the text and store it to title variable
`title= textController.text.trim();`

```
String title;
final textController = TextEditingController();


            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: const [
                TextField(
controller: textController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Title',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Amount',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
title = textController.text.trim();
},
                  child: Text("Add Transaction"),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```